# Using compressed RAM disks for swap in FreeBSD on an early Raspberry Pi board

Tags: freebsd, raspberry-pi, swap, ramdisk

I have an old Raspberry Pi one model B with 256Mb RAM with FreeBSD installed (`12.0-CURRENT`). Since the device has so little memory, I thought I'd try to use compressed swap in RAM, in order to achieve something similar to what `ZRAM` does on Linux, so I did the following.

I had 209Mb RAM, 166Mb free:

```
# freecolor -m -o
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           209         42        166          0          0          0
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Created a memory disk with 50Mb, with `-o compress` so the data will be compressed before being written:

```
# mdconfig -a -t malloc -o compress -o reserve -s 50m -u 7
```

Ok, so I could see that I have 50Mb less available RAM:

```
# freecolor -m -o
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           209         95        114          0          0          0
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Then I activated a swap device on the newly created disk:

```
# swapon /dev/md7
```

So I finally got 50Mb swap, which is mapped onto RAM:

```
# freecolor -m -o
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           209         94        114          0          0          0
Swap:           50          0         50
```

So -- my first quesion is, will this work as expected? (I mean, will data be compressed when pages are swapped onto `/dev/md7`?)

And also, why -- since it seems that I still have 114M of available RAM -- can't I create more ramdisks?

```
# mdconfig -a -t malloc -o compress -o reserve -s 10m -u 8
mdconfig: ioctl(/dev/mdctl): Cannot allocate memory
```